# Jenkins pipeline: doesn't checkout code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm experiencing a weird behavior, I did the first try today with Jenkins Pipeline and tried to run a simple pipeline using the sample provided in the actual pipeline area inside the job.

```
    node {
       def mvnHome
       stage('Preparation') { // for display purposes
          // Get some code from a GitHub repository
          git 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
          // Get the Maven tool.
          // ** NOTE: This 'M3' Maven tool must be configured
          // **       in the global configuration.           
          mvnHome = tool 'M3'
       }
       stage('Build') {
          // Run the maven build
          sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore clean package"
       }
       stage('Results') {
          junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
          archive 'target/*.jar'
       }
    }
```

The strange thing is: When I run the job, it runs the Preparation stage correctly, then goes to Build and fail saying that are no pom.xml to execute, but looking into the execution logs of that all there's no mention to the git operation occurred. I looked into the job folder and there's nothing regarding the git repository that I tried to clone there too.

```
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on master in /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/Test-Pipeline
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Preparation)
    [Pipeline] tool
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Build)
    [Pipeline] sh
    [Test-Pipeline] Running shell script
    + /opt/software/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore                                 clean package
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.057 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-08T22:54:41-05:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/309M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/Test-Pipeline). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

I tried to add url attribute but didn't work either. According the config Pipeline itself should include the git, so I'm guessing what I'm doing wrong here.

My config: 
Jenkins 2.32.3 and Pipeline 2.5

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct to me, not sure if you pasted the whole script, if not, please make sure that you haven't redefined `git` somewhere. E.g. `def git = ...` or similar.

Comment: Indeed, the git tools seems not to be found, I just tested this exact sample code and I have `Cloning the remote Git repository` output. Also, I'm noticing a strange thing in your logs : your job says it is running in path `/Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/Test-Pipeline` whereas your mvn tools is located in `/opt/software/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn`... are you using a strange Windows/Unix mix, like a Windows mounted folder maybe ?

Comment: Thanks @Pom12 - I'm using a Mac, but I will review my config and my git, since I didn't tested with a normal Jenkins build (non-pipeline), since its a brand new installation.

Comment: I will review that @JonS. Thanks

Comment: Guys, I added a sh "git" and it runs the git command fine, so I'm guessing that is not my configuration that is wrong, git seems availalble.

Comment: Strange thing is that it completely ignores the git stage (which suggests that it bound to something else which return nothing) cause if it was missing you would get an error that the step `git`  can't be found...

Comment: i am also experiencing the same issue. in my case, we are using RTC scm and using pipeline syntax, i have generated the groovy syntax. when build started, checkout happens but workspace does not contain all files and folders. i am getting build and compilation issues. i am not sure why the worskapce is half coocked . please suggest

Comment: Maybe the way to debug this is to do the following: 
1. Make it print out the $PATH and make sure that it matches the $PATH you expect.
2. Make sure all the commands in the Jenkins file can be executed with that $PATH, Especially if the $PATH doesn't match the one in your shell environment.

Answer (score 1):

What credentials are used for the checkout? If you select the Lightweight checkout option in the build job definition, the Jenkins will only recover the pipeline script file from SCM, and not checkout the complete repository.

[image]

When checking out via a stage you will probably need credentials, which can be specified in the git call:

```
  stage ("Checkout") {
    git branch: '<branch>',
      credentialsId: '<creds-guid>',
      url: '<repo-url>'
  }
```

The credential id should match the ID of the appropriate credentials in Jenkins Credential store.
[image]

Not asked, but I would also suggest you use the withMaven step to bracket the maven command:

```
  stage ("Build") {
    withMaven(
        globalMavenSettingsConfig: '<config>',
        jdk: '<JDK>',
        maven: 'M3') {

        sh 'mvn <command>'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Snippet Generator to generate the script:
[image: snippetGenerator]

Use the the generated snippet in the pipeline script :
[image]